# How to get different key with single value in dictionary by Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, string, dictionary, nsdictionary

I have a clickable UILabel.
 
And the label text show all dictionary values.
Then when I click, I want to use value to check back the keys.
But if I just have a single value, how to separate keys to each different value label.

[image: Image like this.]

```
//Dictionary Data
self.finalDic = ["11defba4d092ggf00e0fdb5": "@user5 ", "114defba4d092ggf00e0fdb6": "@user6 ", "114defba4d092ggf00e0fdb1": "@user1 ", "114defba4d092ggf00e0fdb3": "@user1 ", "114defba4d092ggf00e0fdb4": "@user4 ", "114defba4d092ggf00e0fdb2": "@user1 "]
```

When I click the first @user1, I will get a key(114defba4d092ggf00e0fdb1).
Then  I click the second @user1, I will get another key(114defba4d092ggf00e0fdb3).
Final I click the third @user1, I will get the last key(114defba4d092ggf00e0fdb2).

What should I do to distribute them to a different label?

```
label.handleMentionTap({ (string) in

        let keys = self.finalDic.allKeys(forValue: "@\(string) ")
        if keys.count > 1 {
            print("--> keys > 1 : \(keys)")
        }else{
            print("--> keys: \(keys)")
        }
})
```

Comment: why not swap key and value in your map? if so, you got value ref, and no need to make a key counter

Comment: So do you have just one single label which holds all the users, or do you have several labels, each for one user?

Comment: okay, I want to show serveral label(@user1), and they have different key.

Comment: @vg0x00 ["@user1 ": "114defba4d092ggf00e0fdb1", "@user1 ":"114defba4d092ggf00e0fdb3", "@user1 ":"114defba4d092ggf00e0fdb2"]  just like this have the same key? Is it legal?

Comment: you don't need to display all the key value in your label, like this: "@user1.(hash1)", "@user1.(hash2)", "@user1.(hash3)" only display the first 5 characters: "@user1, @user1, @user1"

Comment: I know but a label text just "@user1 @user1 @user1", how to find back the key.

Comment: And they don't have repeat key.

Comment: Is this related to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48297093/swift-how-to-make-uilabel-clickable-like-hashtag-and-distinguish-the-same-text#comment83580899_48297093 ? Seems to have the same issue. As I said there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48297093/swift-how-to-make-uilabel-clickable-like-hashtag-and-distinguish-the-same-text#comment83580899_48297093 Because with `label.handleMentionTap({ (string)` there is NO WAY to know if it's the first or second one `@user1` you tapped on, not even talking about your dictionary (which are not ordered!)

Answer (score 0):

You can also make and array which have multiple key-value pairs, and them you can give tags to your label and on tap you can get the value directly based on a tag.

So your `dataArray` will be like this :

```
let dataArray = [ ["11defba4d092ggf00e0fdb5": "@user5 "], ["114defba4d092ggf00e0fdb6": "@user6 "], ["114defba4d092ggf00e0fdb1": "@user1 "], ["114defba4d092ggf00e0fdb3": "@user1 "], ["114defba4d092ggf00e0fdb4": "@user4 "], ["114defba4d092ggf00e0fdb2": "@user1 "]]
```

Anf you can run a for loop to show all the values on your label :

```
for i in 0..<dataArray.count{
    yourLabel.tag = i
    for (key,value) in dataArray[i]{
        print(key, value)
        yourLabel.text = value
    }

}
```

On tap gesture you can get the tag of the label and thus you can get the tapped value from your dataArray based on your tag.